# Progress Dialog issue in below android 4.4.4

Tags: android, styles, progressdialog

I am using progress dialog in my android application.It is looking good on android 5.0+.But in below android 4.4.4 it show two layers.I have attached screen shot.I am using style

```
<style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#CCCCCC</item>
        <item name="android:background">#E43F3F</item>
</style>
```

and progress dialog[image]

```
final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SplashActivity.this,
                    R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
            progressDialog.show();
```

How to fix this issue.Please suggest me.

Comment: try adding `<item android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent" />`  to the style

Comment: did You manage to fix this

Answer (score 2):

You should replace your import from

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
```

to:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: where to put android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog ?

Comment: @IgorVuković replace your import line in the top of the file

Comment: I'am not using AlertDialog as it statest in the question the poblem is in ProgressDialog

Comment: This is not answering to the question, the problem is with ProgressDialog which is not included in import android.support.v7.app; any suggestion ? Your solution is working for AlertDialog.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can add these to your style:

```
<item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
<item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
```

It works well in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I had same situation (tested in API 16), changing import to

```
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
```

or adding

```
<item android:windowBackground="@android:color/transparent" />
```

to the style didn't worked for me.

I have created `values-v21` folder with default material style and added

```
 <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
 <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

to the `style.xml` file in `values` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dedicated style for your ProgressDialog on Android <= API 20.

```
<style name="AppTheme.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ProgressDialog" parent="AppTheme.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then, you have to apply the ProgressDialog style to make it working :

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21)
    {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mActivity, R.style.AppTheme_ProgressDialog);
    }
    else
    {
        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(mActivity);
    }
....
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed this by external library https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs
.Simple and nice.

```
new MaterialDialog.Builder(this)
    .title(R.string.progress_dialog)
    .content(R.string.please_wait)
    .progress(true, 0)
    .progressIndeterminateStyle(true)
    .show();
```